# Problem with JOINs on selection of related data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three entity types (let's call them A, B, C) persisted on three tables of my database.

Each entity type has a relation with the other two entities. Relations are persisted in three tables of the DB as well (let's call them AB, AC, BC), where every record is a couple of IDs of the respective entities.

Relations A-B are one-to-many and are mandatory: every A has at least one relation with a B, every B has a relation with an A.

Relations A-C and B-C are many-to-many and are optional: there can be As without relation with Cs, there can be Bs without relations with Cs.
I cannot change this schema.

I need to build a table with all the As and their related data. Every row of the table must contain only related data or NULLs where there are no relations.
I thought I would be fine with something like:

```
SELECT * -- let's omit columns for simplicity
FROM      AB
LEFT JOIN BC ON BC.IdB = AB.IdB
LEFT JOIN AC ON AC.IdA = AB.IdA AND
                AC.IdC = BC.IdC
INNER JOIN A ON A.Id = AB.IdA
INNER JOIN B ON B.Id = AB.IdB
LEFT JOIN  C ON C.Id = AC.IdC
```

and then filtering with a WHERE clause. My problem is I don't get how, which makes me think I am approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Any hint would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this not recursive i.e. an A has many Bs, each of which can have a number of Cs, each of which can have a number of As?

Comment: I feel like you replacing the real things you have with "A", "B" and "C" doesn't help explain here. What you're describing here sounds like a design flaw, if I am honest.

Comment: @Charlieface I don't understand what you mean with "recursive". I need to take the As, then build rows for each B related to A and for each C related to A and B.

Comment: @Larnu I'm sorry, I thought that abstracting the problem would be more clear. The real case is more complex and involves 6 entities :-(

Comment: So approximate code is: `FROM A LEFT JOIN (AB INNER JOIN B ON B=AB LEFT JOIN BC ON BC=B) ON AB=A LEFT JOIN AC ON AC=A INNER JOIN C ON C=AC OR C=BC` I agree it does sound like you have an incorrect ternary relation here. But without knowing the context can't say